# Automatically restart internet connection when openvpn is disconnected?

Tags: bash, shell, openvpn

When the log of openvpn hit this line `Thu Jan 01 23:47:36 2015 Restart pause, 5 second(s)` like this:

```
Thu Jan 01 23:47:57 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=Fort-Funston, OU=changeme, CN=changeme, name=changeme, emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Thu Jan 01 23:47:57 2015 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Thu Jan 01 23:47:57 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=Fort-Funston, OU=changeme, CN=changeme, name=changeme, emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Thu Jan 01 23:47:59 2015 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Thu Jan 01 23:47:59 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Thu Jan 01 23:47:59 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1420130879,RECONNECTING,connection-reset,,
Thu Jan 01 23:47:59 2015 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

I want to restart my internet, (disconnect modem and reconnect it again). I already wrote this on my `my-account.ovpn`:

```
script-security 2
up client-connect.sh
down client-disconnect.sh
```

my `client-disconnect.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
profile start > /dev/null
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, use more debugging. Write something like this into `client-disconnect.sh` (assuming `profile start` is the command to restart your internet connection):

```
#!/bin/sh
profile start 2>&1 | logger -t 'client-disconnect'
```

Then, check your OpenVPN configuration. If OpenVPN does not run as `root` user, any scripts it starts on shutdown cannot do that either, unfortunately but logically. So if you want something like this, either reduce the security (remove the `user`, `group` and `chroot` directives), or use `sudo` and allow the OpenVPN user to restart your internet connection, passwordlessly.